# How can I check if a route is valid in a .NET Core middleware before UseEndpoints does?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I am using .NET Core 3.1, creating a web api.

My API Controllers are being mapped with the following:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
```

Is there a way that I can perform an action only if a route matches, but before the actual controller action is executed?

I'm in a situation where I need to create an entity in the database before the application logic is executed.

I initially considered a custom middleware, but only to realise that if I place the middleware before `app.UseEndpoints` it would fire for any and all requests (lots of dummy entities would be created), even those that don't route.

If I place it after `app.UseEndpoints` it's too late as the application code will have already executed.

Managing a white list of routes in a middleware that runs before `app.UseEndpoints` was a thought, but would be a maintenance hassle.

So is there a way to hook into the endpoint routing, or an API in the framework that can let me "preemptively" determine if a route is valid?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The call to `UseRouting` does the job of figuring out which endpoint is going to run. If a match is found, it sets the `Endpoint` for the current `HttpContext`. This is available inside a middleware component using [`HttpContext.GetEndpoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.endpointhttpcontextextensions.getendpoint?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Here's an example that uses this approach:

```
app.UseRouting();

app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    // using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    var endpoint = ctx.GetEndpoint();

    if (endpoint != null)
    {
        // An endpoint was matched.
        // ...
    }

    await next();
});

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
```